# upload file into Google drive problems with insert function

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload file to Google drive

parts of code I get from here
[GoogleDriveUpload](https://github.com/hank5000/GoogleDriveUpload)

This is part of code with errors.

```
private File insertFile(com.google.api.services.drive.Drive service, String title, String description,
                        String parentId, String mimeType, final String filename) {
    // File's metadata.
    File body = new File();
    body.setTitle(title);
    body.setDescription(description);
    body.setMimeType(mimeType);

    // Set the parent folder.
    if (parentId != null && parentId.length() > 0) {
        body.setParents(Collections.singletonList(new ParentReference().setId(parentId)));
    }

    // File's content.
    java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(filename);
    if(!fileContent.canRead()) {
        ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Dialog wrong = new Dialog(context);
                wrong.setTitle("file ("+filename+") is not readable");
                wrong.show();
            }
        });
        return null;
    }


    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(mimeType, fileContent);

    try {
        com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Files.Insert insert = service.files().insert(body,mediaContent);

        MediaHttpUploader uploader = insert.getMediaHttpUploader();
        uploader.setChunkSize(1 * 1024 * 1024);
        uploader.setProgressListener(new FileUploadProgressListener(filename));

        File file = insert.execute();

        return file;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ERROR OCCURED : " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

I can't build project and have errors:

```
Error:(464, 13) error: cannot find symbol method setTitle(String)
Error:(470, 54) error: incompatible types: List<ParentReference> cannot be converted to List<String>
Error:(491, 54) error: cannot find symbol class Insert
Error:(491, 86) error: cannot find symbol method insert(File,FileContent)
```

Have any idea?